# Return characters up to first nonalphanumeric character

Tags: php, regex

I want to obtain a part of a string up until the first non-alphanumeric character. 
Currently, I have the following strings with what I would like to show.

```
Go Forty Go (IRE) 471    -> Go Forty Go
Pearl Noir 15528258 D3   -> Pearl Noir
Synonym (ITY) 1793158-00 D1   -> Synonym
```

In the above cases, I want to pull characters before either a number or a `(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\h*[^ a-zA-Z].*$/', '', $input);
Go Forty Go
Pearl Noir
Synonym
```

btw this is removing after first non-alphabetic+non-space character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM8uX9/1)

Comment: When i run the above i get the same output :S
[code]
$repl =  preg_replace('/[^ a-zA-Z].*$/', '', $dropresults->childNodes->item(8)->textContent);[/code]

echo $repl."<br />";

Comment: Check my linked demo to see values getting replaced. What does `var_dump($dropresults->childNodes->item(8)->textContent);` show to you? Moreover try: '/\h*[^ a-zA-Z].*$/m' regex

Comment: string(82) " Beau Mistral (IRE) 158-59316 D2 "

Comment: '/\h*[^ a-zA-Z].*$/m' just deletes all the text

Comment: [No, that's not correct, you can check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM8uX9/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^.*?(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])/

$str = "Go Forty Go (IRE) 471    -> Go Forty Go";
$str2 = "Pearl Noir 15528258 D3   -> Pearl Noir";
$str3 = "Synonym (ITY) 1793158-00 D1   -> Synonym";
preg_match('/^.*?(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])/', $str, $match);
echo $match[0] . PHP_EOL;
preg_match('/^.*?(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])/', $str2, $match1);
echo $match1[0] . PHP_EOL;
preg_match('/^.*?(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])/', $str3, $match2);
echo $match2[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

See [IDEONE code](https://ideone.com/V9GX5w)

Output:

```
Go Forty Go
Pearl Noir
Synonym
```

The "core" of the regex is `(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])` look-ahead that makes matching stop at a non-letter or space preceded with optional whitespace (to trim the output).

If you have Unicode letters in your input, add `u` flag:

```
/^.*?(?=\s*[^\s\p{L}])/u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
>>> preg_match_all("/^(.*?)\s*[(0-9]/m",$s, $matches)
=> 3
>>> $matches[1]
=> [   
       "Go Forty Go",
       "Pearl Noir",
       "Synonym"
   ]
```